# Scalatra example fails to start

Tags: scala, scalatra

I decided to try Scalatra out. But the server does not seem to start, and the commands do not return any errors.

I first got the scalatra project from GitHub:

```
git clone http://github.com/scalatra/scalatra-sbt-prototype.git
```

then ran sbt:

```
java -jar "/path/to/sbt-launch.jar" jetty-run
```

and got this (after dependencies were downloaded):

```
[info] Loading project definition from /home/platon/PrF/scalatra/scalatra-sbt-prototype/project
[info] Set current project to scalatra-sbt-prototype (in build file:/home/platon/PrF/scalatra/scalatra-sbt-prototype/)
[info] jetty-7.4.5.v20110725
[info] NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
[info] started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/home/platon/PrF/scalatra/scalatra-sbt-prototype/target/webapp/},/home/platon/PrF/scalatra/scalatra-sbt-prototype/target/webapp
[info] Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080 STARTING
```

But at `http://localhost:8080`, I see nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It says it is listening. Is there a java process listening on port 8080? Is there a java process running at all? What, exactly, happens when you try to open that page?

Comment: No, there was nothing listening or running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
java -jar "sbt-launch.jar"
jetty-run
```

That will drop you in the sbt console where you can do jetty-run, otherwise the process starts and stops again immediately

Comment: Yes, this was exactly the problem. Being new to sbt :)